# Nodes Connecting to and from Multiple Other Nodes (in JavaScript or Ruby preferably)

Tags: javascript, ruby, data-structures, nodes, graph-theory

I'm a newbie to data structures + algorithms, and while practicing interview questions, I came across the following:
say that we have individual nodes connecting to and from other (possibly multiple) nodes:

> (1) Generate the data structure to store it all
>
> (2) Generate the function to retrieve a list of all the nodes within "n"
>   hops from a particular node

I'm particularly not sure about what "data structure" to use. I thought okay, maybe we can create a node class, and have an array to reference all the nodes that a particular node points to. Then, in order to find the nodes that are within "n" hops from a particular node, we can iterate through that array of nodes, recursively call the function (passing n-1 this time) until we hit a base case of "1" hops. Could someone explain the error in my thinking and/or improve on it?

Appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: Why do you think there's an error in your thinking?

Comment: @Pointy, I suppose it makes sense in my head. But when it asks for "data structure," I assume there might be a better way to represent a node than as an object of a class that we simply create and call "Node".

Comment: Well you don't have many choices beyond that in JavaScript :)  One thing to consider (maybe; I'm not a big graph algorithm person) is whether the data structure should make explicit provisions for providing "markers" or something to assist with traversal/search algorithms. In other words, ways to keep track of nodes that have been visited during some particular operation.